# Optimize htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I have a htaccess file with around 200 lines, and the htaccess contains mostly Rewrite rules. The file itself works great.

But I wonder if there are a faster way to rewrite this attached rule:

```
RewriteRule "^order/new/(.+)$" "extention.php?sale&subroute=order&route=new&cid=$1" [QSA,L]
RewriteRule "^order/view/(.+)$" "extention.php?sale&route=view&subroute=order&id=$1" [QSA,L]
RewriteRule "^order/edit/(.+)$" "extention.php?sale&route=edit&subroute=order&id=$1" [QSA,L]
RewriteRule "^order/copy/(.+)$" "extention.php?sale&route=copy&subroute=order&id=$1" [QSA,L]
```

Is there a way to group all this lines into one?

E.g: Something like:

```
RewriteRule "^order/{copy|view|new|edit}/(.+)$" "extention.php?route=$1 &subroute=order&id=$2" [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about speed, move all your configuration into your vhost configuration file and disable .htaccess files. Currently, every time a request comes in, Apache reads your .htaccess file. The vhost configuration is read once on startup and the rules are kept in memory, which speeds up processing of your rules.

As for the question at hand, you can combine these 4 rules by using another capture group. Capture groups are surrounded by `(` and `)` brackets, not curly brackets. You would end up with a rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^order/(new|view|edit|copy)/(.+)$ extention.php?sale&route=$1&subroute=order&id=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Or even a more generic:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ extention.php?sale&route=$2&subroute=$1&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```